# Custom Tab's text is not highlighted in the Tablayout

Tags: android

I have made a `CustomView` for the tabs in the `TabLayout that contains a`TextView`for the tab title and`ImageView`for the icons`

But when I click on a tab, the text for the selected tab is not highlighted!
I have tried every combination of XML attributes for the tablayout wigdet and nothing is working out. I tried to Google the problem, but couldn't find any solutions.

**MainActivity.class**

The implemeneation of the Tablayoyut with custom view.

```
    mainTablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_activity_main);
    mainViewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_viewpager);

    mainTablayout.addTab(mainTablayout.newTab().setText("Search"));
    mainTablayout.addTab(mainTablayout.newTab().setText("Inbox"));
    mainTablayout.addTab(mainTablayout.newTab().setText("Edit"));
    mainTablayout.addTab(mainTablayout.newTab().setText("Profile"));

    mainTablayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tablayout).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search);
    mainTablayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tablayout).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_envelope);
    mainTablayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tablayout).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_cogwheel);
    mainTablayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tablayout).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile_1);


    mainViewpager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mainViewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mainTablayout));
    mainTablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

**custom_tablayout.xml:**

The layout for the custom tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView

    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

This is the attribute used on the Tablayout wigdet

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout_activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tablayout_activity_main"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_off"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to select the tab through the tab-layout.

I'm using com.android.support:design:23.2.1 support library.Using below code you can highlight selected tab.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

You can refer following link: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout